# Pick each column value on different criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Query as below:

```
SELECT urban_appr, urban_in, rural_appr, rural_in, ground_appr, ground_in 
FROM <table>
```

In the above query, I have to add WHERE clause as follows:

- For urban values, `WHERE scheme_type = 'U'`
- For rural values, `WHERE scheme_type = 'R'`
- For ground values, `WHERE scheme_type = 'E'`

I want all this using single SQL query. I am using SQL Server 2005.

Edited:

Added image below of the actual problem. You can see that it is showing district BR as two records, whereas I want it in one row.

[image]

Comment: Hello *Mr Repeating Group*. Read about [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) then split your table into two

Comment: @Bohemian That is not possible. I have to query an existing database designed by someone else.

Comment: What is the value of `scheme_type` for that `district_nm = 'BR'` row?? Do you have two rows in the original data?? One for `district_nm = 'BR' and scheme_type = 'R'` and another for `district_nm = 'BR' and scheme_type = 'E'`, or how does this work??

Comment: No, I have one row. The first two columns are 'U', the second two are 'R' and the last two are 'E'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOIN` to bring all rows for each `district_nm` into one row:

```
select
    district_nm,
    t1.urban_appr, t1.urban_in,
    t2.rural_appr, t2.rural_in,
    t3.ground_appr, t3.ground_in
from <table> t1
join <table> t2 on t2.district_nm = t1.district_nm and t2.scheme_type = 'R'
join <table> t3 on t3.district_nm = t1.district_nm and t3.scheme_type = 'E'
where t1.scheme_type = 'U';
```

You can add more conditions to the where clause as you like, eg `and t1.district_nm = 'x'`

Consider creating a view from the above query and use that in our app instead:

```
create view table_view as
<above query>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this looks ugly - but try this...

```
SELECT ISNULL(district_nm,nm) district_nm,
  URBAN_APPR,
  URBAN_IN,
  RURAL_APPR,
  RURAL_IN,
  ground_appr,
  ground_in
FROM
  (SELECT ISNULL(a.district_nm, b.district_nm) nm,
    urban_appr,
    urban_in,
    rural_appr,
    rural_in
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTRICT_NM,
      URBAN_APPR,
      URBAN_IN
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE SCHEME_TYPE = 'U'
    ) a
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    (SELECT DISTRICT_NM,
      RURAL_APPR,
      RURAL_IN
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE SCHEME_TYPE = 'R'
    )B)
  ON a.district_nm = b.district_nm
  ) temp
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  (SELECT DISTRICT_NM,
    GROUND_APPR,
    GROUND_IN
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE SCHEME_TYPE = 'E'
  )c)
ON temp.nm = c.district_nm;
```

Comment: No it is not working correctly. It is showing a common set of rows in all categories.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this - selecting different columns depending on the type of your values??

```
SELECT urban_appr, urban_in, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'U'
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, rural_appr, rural_in, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'R'
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ground_appr, ground_in
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'E'
```

???

**Update:** so you want to add another column and group by it:

```
SELECT district_nm, urban_appr, urban_in, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'U'
UNION
SELECT district_nm, NULL, NULL, rural_appr, rural_in, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'R'
UNION
SELECT district_nm, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ground_appr, ground_in
FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE scheme_type = 'E'
GROUP BY district_nm
```

Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: Ok, I need to add one more column (district_nm) that will be the first column and I want to Group By on this column.

Comment: Yes it works but the problem is that if any district has reocrds in all categories, i.e., U, R and E, then instead of displaying records of that district in one row, it displays in three rows.

Comment: @RPK: you need to **show us** some sample data and explain in more detail what it is you really want .....